# Azure: container didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8080

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, azure, azure-web-app-service

I've suddenly started getting this error even though my app runs fine locally.

I'm running a rails app on Azure App Service.

I've tried setting an application setting PORT to 80 and my WEBSITES_PORT to 8080 with no luck.

puma.rb includes this

```
port        ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3000 }
```

I've tried changing this to 8080 with no luck after deploying to Azure.

After looking online I'm really stuck as to why this is happening suddenly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure web application only support 80 and 443 port， but you could use `WEBSITES_PORT` point to other port. The variable `"PORT"` appears to be obsolete and may conflict with `WEBSITES_PORT`.

So my suggestion is deleting `"PORT"`. Use `WEBSITE_PORT` directly to specify the desired port, such as 8080. By the way, the port must be the container exposes.

Comment: Not sure why the ports changed in the first place. It was either this, or some routing errors that I could only see locally. But most likely ports as I was getting HTTP errors.

Comment: Is it WEBSITES_PORT or WEBSITE_PORT?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and was looking around at SO posts for hours. I tried changing the PORT and WEBSITES_PORT variables to no avail. What ended up being my problem was my app was deploying on port 8001, and the deployment was trying to ping 8000. I had to change my app to run on 8000